# Android SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the Android SQLiteAssetHelper to load a populated .db file into my android app. However using the following code it doesn't actually make the database.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


public Question getRandQuestion(String category){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String sqlTables = category;

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + category + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
    Question question = new Question(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)), c.getString(1),
            c.getString(2), Uri.parse(c.getString(3)));
    return question;
}

}
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
```

I call the DataBaseHelper  constructor within another class like so:

Play Class:

```
    private DataBaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    db=new DataBaseHelper(this);
```

I then access the getRandQuestion method within DataBaseHelper but i get the error stated above when trying to open a readable database.

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Enitre stack trace:

```
01-29 18:27:02.228 3867-3867/com.example.anthony.triviaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.anthony.triviaapp, PID: 3867
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anthony.triviaapp/com.example.anthony.TriviaApplication.Play}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
                                                                             at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
                                                                             at com.example.anthony.TriviaApplication.DataBaseHelper.getRandQuestion(DataBaseHelper.java:44)
                                                                             at com.example.anthony.TriviaApplication.Play.CreateQuiz(Play.java:83)
                                                                             at com.example.anthony.TriviaApplication.Play.onCreate(Play.java:30)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @user5792452 Are you sure the file path is correct? `assets/databases/quiz.db`

Comment: Check LogCat above the stack trace and look for messages, possibly at `warning` severity, that refer to "database". It feels like the attempt to unpack your database is failing, perhaps for the reason mentioned by PPartisan. The log message may give you more clues.

Comment: Note that `SQLiteAssetHelper` is **not** a standard Android class.

Comment: the path is correct, and the log says something about file being encrypted or not a database or possible corruption.